# UIPopover from UIButton in UITableViewCell

Tags: objective-c, ipad

I have a UIButton inside a cell that is inside a tableView.

When the button is clicked, I want a popover to show up at that button.

Are there any examples of this?

Note: I am new at this, and still not familiar with coding.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The [*View Controller Programming Guide*](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/iPadControllers/iPadControllers.html) is a good place to start:

And these example apps use popovers:

- http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MultipleDetailViews/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009775
- http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/ToolbarSearch/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009461